# 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method hitTestPoint through a reference with static type Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

im trying to make collision detection in my game and the tutorial is using hitTestPoint, here is the part of the code that wont work if anyone can help. Ground is just a block movie clip and player is, well the player:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

function loop(e:Event):void
{
    if (ground.hitTestPoint(borat.x + leftBumpPoint.x,borat.y + leftBumpPoint.y,true))
    {
        trace("leftBumping");
        leftBumping = true;
    }
    else
    {
        leftBumping = false;
    }

    if (ground.hitTestPoint(borat.x + rightBumpPoint.x,borat.y + rightBumpPoint.y,true))
    {
        trace("rightBumping");
        rightBumping = true;
    }
    else
    {
        rightBumping = false;
    }

    if (ground.hitTestPoint(borat.x + upBumpPoint.x,borat.y + upBumpPoint.y,true))
    {
        trace("upBumping");
        upBumping = true;
    }
    else
    {
        upBumping = false;
    }

    if (ground.hitTestPoint(borat.x + downBumpPoint.x,borat.y + downBumpPoint.y,true))
    {
        trace("downBumping");
        downBumping = true;
    }
    else
    {
        downBumping = false;
    }

}
```

I keep on getting these errors:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 37  1061: Call to a possibly undefined method hitTestPoint through a reference with static type Class.

Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 47  1061: Call to a possibly undefined method hitTestPoint through a reference with static type Class.

Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 57  1061: Call to a possibly undefined method hitTestPoint through a reference with static type Class.

Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 67  1061: Call to a possibly undefined method hitTestPoint through a reference with static type Class.
```

Thank you to anyone who took the time to read this!

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of ground? It has to be an instance of MovieClip for this to work, you can't call that method on a Class.

```
//this will work
var ground:MovieClip = new SomeAsset();
ground.hitTestPoint();

//this won't
SomeAsset.hitTestPoint();
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, but now I get this error:

`Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 8 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method ground.`
I imported flash.display.MovieClip; but it still wont work
I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Seems like something is trying to call a function that is not a function. Something like `foo.ground()` Make sure you are calling defined methods.

Comment: Sorry to ask but what should I do to make a defined method, ground is a movieclip on the stage that is just a block and I placed multiple grounds to make a stage for my game, thank you soo much for helping

Comment: If ground is a movieclip you can't use it like a function like this `ground()`. To make a function you just do `function myFunction():void{}` Then you can call it using its name with `myFunction()`